# Powershell v2 prompting for value in foreach

Tags: windows, powershell

This code runs in PowerShell v1 but not in PowerShell v2. It now prompts for a value:

[image]

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Filter "*.journal" | 
 Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'SoundPC\[\d{1,12}-\d{1,12}\].journal' } | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | ForEach-Object 
{

$sourcefile = $_.Name

}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Weird. But if I move the left curly brace up onto the same line as the "ForEach-Object {" it works! What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening brace must be on the same line as the foreach command, currently its on a new line:

```
Foreach-Object {...
```

Comment: I really wish they'd allow that so it's consistent.  Foreach lets you put the brace on the next line.  Foreach-object doesn't.

Comment: Another alternative is to end the Foreach-Object line with a backtick `. Shay's approach is better if you're writing a new script, but if you're modifying existing scripts where this is used a lot, adding the backtick may be faster.

Comment: I agree to some extent. There are just a few characters that perform as line continuators: '` | {' and un-closed opening quotes (single or double), and they must be on the same line of the command. Allowing the -process brace to start on a new line would be the equivalent of 'gci <newline> c:\'.

Answer (score 0):

As Shay Levy pointed out, the brace must be on the same line as the `ForEach-Object` command.

```
... | ForEach-Object {
    $sourcefile = $_.Name
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the backtick character ` at the end of the line to cause a continuation, which will then allow you to put the opening brace on the next line. Being a C# developer, I prefer this so that my braces can line up.

```
... | ForEach-Object `
{
    $sourcefile = $_.Name
}
```